# Running gulp and set environment in Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, gulp, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Windows 10 Pro. Recently I changed from Ubuntu to Windows 64-bit.
In Ubuntu I ran node.js applications by setting the environment variable and using node.js package `gulp`. Now I don't know how to run both commands at a time in Command Prompt or Windows PowerShell. I installed git-bash and Cygwin too.

Below I'm providing the command which I used in Ubuntu. I searched Google and Github. Nothing helped me. I installed `gulp` globally.

Command is `env ENV=development gulp` in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a (volatile) environment variable and executing a command in CMD:

```
set "ENV=development"
gulp
```

In one line:

```
set "ENV=development" & gulp
```

---

Defining a (volatile) environment variable and executing a command in PowerShell:

```
$env:ENV = 'development'
& gulp
```

In one line:

```
$env:ENV = 'development'; & gulp
```

Comment: where should(command prompt, powershell, git bash) i execute these commands..??

Comment: i have to mention ssh configuration too before executing above commands

Answer (score 0):

**Approach I**

Create a batch file and set all the required environment values & execute your command

build.bat:

```
set ENV=development
start cmd /k "cd <app-directory> & call gulp"
```

**Approach II**

Setting environment value in package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "scripts": {
    "gulp": "ENV='development' gulp"
  },
  ...
}
npm run gulp // Command to run the gulp task
```

**Approach III**

Setting environment value in gulpfile.js  [gulp-env](https://github.com/crystalschang/gulp-env) module

```
// gulpfile.js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var nodemon = require('nodemon');
var env = require('gulp-env');

gulp.task('nodemon', function() {
    // nodemon server (just an example task)
});

gulp.task('set-env', function () {
  env({
    vars: {
        ENV: "development"
    }
  })
});

gulp.task('default', ['set-env', 'nodemon'])
```